# (Passenger Agent) Signal received. Gracefully shutting down

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have a rails application that I am deploying on an aws ec2 instance, this is my first time using the Rubber Gem, for which I have followed [this tutorial](https://liggat.org/a-full-AWS-rails-stack-provision-and-deployment-with-the-rubber-gem/).
After removing the default nginx configurations and after intial deployment (step 5 of the tutorial I have mentioned) when ever I try and access my app using the public IP or DNS I get a 403 Forbidden nginx screen.
On inspecting the error log of nginx on the server this is what I found. I have been stuck on this issue for quite sometime now, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7236 13522/7fc24be3a780 age/Wat/Main.cpp:1264 ]: Starting PassengerAgent watchdog...
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7526 13525/7f2f7f588780 age/Hel/Main.cpp:944 ]: Starting PassengerAgent server...
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7529 13525/7f2f7f588780 age/Hel/Main.cpp:237 ]: PassengerAgent server running in multi-application mode.
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7550 13525/7f2f7f588780 age/Hel/Main.cpp:698 ]: PassengerAgent server online, PID 13525
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7851 13530/7f39b592e780 age/Log/Main.cpp:442 ]: Starting PassengerAgent logger...
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7863 13530/7f39b592e780 age/Log/Main.cpp:323 ]: PassengerAgent logger online, PID 13530
[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7876 13525/7f2f7f588780 age/Hel/Main.cpp:857 ]: Watchdog seems to be killed; forcing shutdown of all subprocesses

[ 2015-07-10 05:49:13.7877 13525/7f2f79042700 age/Hel/Main.cpp:508 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
2015/07/10 05:49:13 [alert] 9729#0: Required key 'core_address' is missing (-1: Unknown error)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and I was able to clear up the issue by updating the version of passenger in the rubber-passenger_nginx.yml to passenger_version: '1:5.0.13-1~`lsb_release -sc`1'.